# How to get count for different values in different columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have a chart table like below

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|  ID | REGION | STATUS | CLOSED_DT |HEALTH  | Open_DT     |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
|   1 | QA     | open   |  -        |  red   | 2016-01-03  |
|   2 | QA     | open   |  -        | green  | 2015-03-03  |
|   3 | QA     | open   |  -        | orange | 2016-02-03  |
|   4 | QA     | open   |  -        | red    | 2016-01-03  |
|   5 | x      | closed |  16-03-03 | green  | 2015-06-03  |
|   6 | Req    | open   |  -        | orange | 2015-05-03  |
|   7 | x      | closed |  16-02-02 | green  | 2015-05-03  |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to display three charts - bar chart , pie chart , month wise trend chart. First chart requires count of different region for open status.

> select region, count (*) as total from chart where STATUS='open' group by region;

I used the above query for bar chart. For pie chart i used the below query

> select health, count (*) as total from chart where STATUS='open' group by health;

Next is month wise chart where i need to display for the last twelve month For eg from Jan to Dec , i need number of open and closed for each month. How to frame the query to get the count of open and closed status for last twelve months from current date. Also instead of executing three different queries for each chart , is there any way to use a single query. I need query for both Oracle and Mssql

Comment: You should tag a question with the database you are actually using.  Why do you need both Oracle and SQL Server?

Comment: Actually i am using oracle and mssql . I need to display charts for data that is in oracle as well as mssql. Thats why tagged both. For 2 systems i need to display the charts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT to_char(Open_DT,'YYYY') as yearCol, to_char(Open_DT,'MM') as MonthCol,
       count(CASE WHEN status = 'open' then 1 end) as openCnt,
       count(CASE WHEN status = 'closed' then 1 end) as closeCnt
FROM YourTable
WHERE Open_DT >= add_months(sysdate,-13) 
GROUP BY to_char(Open_DT,'YYYY'),to_char(Open_DT,'MM')
```

You tagged both sql-server and oracle, the above solution is for oracle

For sql server :

```
SELECT year(Open_DT) as yearCol, month(Open_DT) as MonthCol,
       count(CASE WHEN status = 'open' then 1 end) as openCnt,
       count(CASE WHEN status = 'closed' then 1 end) as closeCnt
FROM YourTable
WHERE Open_DT > DATEADD(month,-13,getdate())
GROUP BY year(Open_DT),month(Open_DT)
```

Comment: How to get last 13 month from today and then use it in the query

Comment: Also for each chart having a separate query is better or a single query?

Comment: Depends on a lot of things, but yes I believe a separate query for each chart is better. @hemamalini

Comment: thanks a lot . Above query works . But suppose if i did not have any data for a month (within 13 months) For example, in Dec 2015 I did not have any incidents open and closed I should get like for Dec 2015 both open and closed count as zero . But above query i am not getting the Dec month itself

Comment: Is there any way to get that data?